# DETAIL: Key (user_id)=(1) is not present in table "auth_user". )

Tags: python, django, django-models, token, django-users

I'm trying to use Django AbstractBaseUser for my member area.
When I try to add a new super user, I get this error :

`The above exception (insert or update on table "authtoken_token" violates foreign key constraint "authtoken_token_user_id_35299eff_fk_auth_user_id" DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) is not present in table "auth_user". )`

I don't know where is my mistake.

I think this is about the app **rest_framework.authtoken** which doesn't work correctly...
This is my code :

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'users',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.Account'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

...

class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, name, username, email, phone, password=None):
        if not name:
            raise ValueError("User must have a name")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("User must have an unique username")
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an unique email address")
        if not phone:
            raise ValueError("User must have a phone number")

        user = self.model(
            name = name,
            username = username,
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            phone = phone,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using = self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, name, username, email, phone, password=None):

        user = self.create_user(
            name = name,
            username = username,
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            phone = phone,
            password = password,
        )

        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using = self._db)

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^0[0-9, " "]+$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '06 00 00 00 00'. Up to 10 digits allowed.")
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=14, null=False, blank=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'username', 'phone']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email + ' : ' + self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True


@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Thanks by advance for your help

Comment: in your create_superuser method return user at the end after the user is saved.

Comment: @ngawang13 I tried that but I still get the same error ...

Comment: @ngawang13 Finally I just reset my database and it worked ! Thanks !!